# Searching PostgreSQL with Django and passing a null or empty string value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm searching Postgres as follows:

```
search_term = self.request.GET.get('search')
queryset = Package.objects.filter(package_description__search=search_term)
```

How do I make this return all objects if search_term is `None` or an empty string?

I've tried setting search_term to `None` or an empty string.

Comment: `if` `else` statement can do it, maybe you just need to do it with one query

Comment: so there's nothing I can pass to have a query ignore the query?

Comment: as far as I know, no! wait for other answers, in the meanwhile, I'm working on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django execute query only at moment when you try to get items of the query. So you can simple add `if` and combine your query

```
search_term = self.request.GET.get('search')
queryset = Package.objects.all()
if search_term:
    queryset = queryset.filter(package_description__search=search_term)
```

link to the doc [querysets-are-lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) thank @bdoubleu

Comment: that "all()" on the second line will cause the query to be run.  Use all() after the completion of the "if" block

Comment: @ChrisCurvey it's correct as is, [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) so it isn't evaluated until it's returned or printed or whatever.